# Azure Data Factory Cost Optimization

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have to use for each loop in Azure Data Factory. Each loop has 2 activities. We have to run this inner activity almost 1000 times daily. Will it impact the cost of usage of Azure Data factory? does it costs per each activity run?

Comment: Hi@Kumud Awasthi Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi @Kumud Awasthi. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. : )

Answer (score 0):

If you have to  run this inner activity almost 1000 times daily, it will impact the cost of usage of Azure Data factory. Pipeline execution activities are charged by the hour except Data movement which is charged in units of DIU-hour.

**Pipeline Execution:**
This is the cost for the compute resources required for Pipeline execution. According to [Data Pipeline Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/). You can expect the bulk of the cost for Azure Data Factory pipelines to fall into this category. This is further divided into three sub-categories :

- **Data movement activities :** This covers the cost of moving data across data stores in activities such as the copy data activity.
- **Pipeline activities :** Pipeline activities such as Lookup, Delete and schema operations during authoring (test connection, browse folder list and table list, get schema, and preview data).
- **External activities :** These are data transformation activities that execute in a computing environment such as Azure Databricks or Azure HDInsight. You can find a list of external activities [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/transform-data).

Each sub-category has separate pricing, as listed below:
**Self hosted**

- Data movement : $0.10/hour
- Pipeline activities : $0.002/hour
- External activities : $0.0001/hour

**Azure Integration runtime**

- Data movement : $0.25/DIU-hour
- Pipeline activities : $0.005/hour
- External activities : $0.00025/hour

In general, if your pipeline activities do not involve data movement, they are billed according to the total execution time of each activity run.

**For eaxmple:**
In one pipeline execution, if ForEach activity contains 3 Lookup acitivities, you will pay for these 4 activities.
[image]